# VB.NET using ProcessName

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I created a program with functions read an application by process name ...

When Calc.exe is run Label31 changed from CLOSE into the OPEN, but when I close Calc.exe Label31 do not want to change back from OPEN into the CLOSE...

My Code

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
Dim myProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("calc")
    For Each Read As Process In myProcess
        Label31.Text = "OPEN"
    Next
End Sub
```

anyone can help me how to calc when closed label31 changed from OPEN into CLOSE?

Comment: Your code only checks if `calc.exe` is open when `Form1_Load()` is triggered. You will need to continously check the status of the process periodically to update the label. You may want to use a Timer control

Comment: i forgot my new code using timer function but same with Form1_Load()

Answer (score 0):

If you're **polling** then just do:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim myProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("calc")
    Label31.Text = If(myProcess.Length > 0, "OPEN", "CLOSED")
End Sub
```